# OpenERP XMLRPC: How to fetch a list of all ids that belongs to a given model?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, openerp-7

I am aware that I have to structure my xmlrpc query like this:

```
ids = execute(dbname, uid, pwd, model, 'search', args)
fields = ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c']
elements = execute(dbname, uid, pwd, model, 'read', ids, fields)
```

I need help on structuring the `args` parameter in order to fetch a list of available elements from these models:

- **res.users** as in `Settings->Users`
- **res.company** as in `Settings->Companies`
- **res.partners** as in `Sales->Customers` and `Purchases->Suppliers`
- **sale.order** as in `Sales->Sales Orders`
- **account.invoice** as in `Accounting->Customer Invoices`
- **purchase.order** as in `Purchases->Quotations` and  `Purchases->Purchase Orders`

**UPDATE 1**

Each model fetch request should return all the ids that belong to a given company id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer at [OpenERP Q & A](http://help.openerp.com/question/49670/xmlrpc-how-to-fetch-a-list-of-all-ids-that-belongs-to-a-given-model/), and by [Martin H. Bramwell](http://help.openerp.com/users/285/12480/).  Mine follows:

I see a lot of articles all over the internet talking about how to use xmlrpc on OpenERP 7 and all of them seem to be based on the xmlrpc documentation from the OpenERP 6.

Although not too sure, I think the xmlrpc docs from v6 is mostly outdated for v7.

For starters, there are new methods and endpoints on v7. They are:

```
Method read | /web/dataset/search_read
Method authenticate | /web/session/authenticate
Method get_session_info | /web/session/get_session_info
Method destroy | /web/session/destroy
```

For those like me interested in implementing a php app, I found this very handy library called [php-oe-json](https://github.com/0k/php-oe-json) hosted at github.

Here are some examples on how to retrieve data from OpenERP 7 using php-oe-json

```php
$oe = new PhpOeJson\OpenERP('http://localhost:8069', 'database_name'); 
$oe->login('admin', 'pwd');
// Get a list of records from a model.
$products = $oe->read(array(
   'model' => 'product.product',
   'fields' => array('name', 'id'),
   'limit' => 20,
   // XXXvlab: bug of openerp 7.0+ which will default domain to "None" if not set, and
   // override of ``_search`` doesn't support ``None`` value.
   'domain' => array(),
));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);

// Get a single record from a model.
$so = $oe->read(array(
   'model' => 'sale.order',
   'fields' => array('name', 'id'),
   'limit' => FALSE,
   'domain' => array(array('company_id', '=', 1), array('name', '=', 'SO002')),
));

print_r($so);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `args` parameter may be used to pass conditions for matching records (sql `where` clause):

```
args = [('name', '=', 'admin')]
ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.users', 'search', args)
```

will retrieve the id for the admin user record (if any).

`args` is an array of 3-tuples.

Docs here: https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/

Comment: This approach does not work. Even if it did, I expect it would only return a single array element, that is the admin user element. Following your example, I actually wanted it to return all the user ids under a given company. I also tried args = [('company_id', '=', 1)] but that does not work either.